# Convert .CSV data, with regEx?

Tags: regex, csv

I have a .CSV containing the following data:

```
"http://iis.se/write-content/?submitted","The intro","<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dictum lectus eget enim condimentum, eget bibendum libero porta. Suspendisse vestibulum libero nisl, quis tempus nisl semper in. Ut mi nisl, vehicula quis tristique ut, molestie et est. Donec auctor, ante eu venenatis aliquam, felis nisi pretium turpis, ut mattis dui orci et sem. Duis vitae accumsan velit. Sed tristique lacus nisl, vehicula congue turpis ultrices sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed dictum scelerisque nibh non venenatis. In viverra eros non arcu pellentesque, nec pulvinar turpis placerat.</p> <p>Proin suscipit metus vitae nisi dignissim ullamcorper. Nullam eleifend tempor ligula, sit amet semper metus.</p><p>Proin bibendum bibendum suscipit. Cras pretium lectus sit amet urna interdum, in ultricies eros scelerisque. Pellentesque id condimentum libero. Aenean placerat orci a dictum pharetra. Pellentesque sagittis egestas gravida. Pellentesque suscipit mauris neque, quis auctor lacus blandit et. Curabitur a quam a velit condimentum tristique. Morbi volutpat pulvinar viverra. Duis cursus lectus ac sem dictum, eu tempor risus blandit. In accumsan arcu at lorem mattis lacinia. Vestibulum vitae mollis sem, nec commodo nunc. Donec vel ultricies nunc. Nam at sapien nec libero aliquam pharetra vitae eget leo.</p><p>Read more here <a href=""http://www.google.com"">here</a></p>","Thank you!"
"http://website.com/add/?submitted","The, nice, Second","<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dictum lectus eget enim condimentum, eget bibendum libero porta. Suspendisse vestibulum libero nisl, quis tempus nisl semper in. Ut mi nisl, vehicula quis tristique ut, molestie et est. <a href=""http://www.altavista.com"">Donec auctor</a>, ante eu venenatis aliquam, felis nisi pretium turpis, ut mattis dui orci et sem. Duis vitae accumsan velit. Sed tristique lacus nisl, vehicula congue turpis ultrices sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed dictum scelerisque nibh non venenatis. In viverra eros non arcu pellentesque, nec pulvinar turpis placerat.</p> <p>Proin suscipit metus vitae nisi dignissim ullamcorper. Nullam eleifend tempor ligula, sit amet semper metus.</p><p>Proin bibendum bibendum suscipit. Cras pretium lectus sit amet urna interdum, in ultricies eros scelerisque. Pellentesque id condimentum libero. Aenean placerat orci a dictum pharetra. Pellentesque sagittis egestas gravida. Pellentesque suscipit mauris neque, quis auctor lacus blandit et. Curabitur a quam a velit condimentum tristique. Morbi volutpat pulvinar viverra. Duis cursus lectus ac sem dictum, eu tempor risus blandit. In accumsan arcu at lorem mattis lacinia. Vestibulum vitae mollis sem, nec commodo nunc. Donec vel ultricies nunc. Nam at sapien nec libero aliquam pharetra vitae eget leo.</p>","Thank you!, even more!!!"
```

Simply,

- In COL1, I want to strip everything after the top domain
- In COL2, I want commas, spaces to become hyphens, but it may not double hyphens at any point
- COL1 and COL2 shall be merged into (The Output) COL1
- In COL3, everything should be removed besides the domain contained within `<a> </a>`
- COL4 is untouchable

So, in this case, I want the output to become:

```
"http://iis.se/the-intro","http://www.google.com","Thank you!"
"http://website.com/the-nice-second","http://www.altavista.com","Thank you!, even more!!!"
```

Is it possible or very advanced?

I am thinking a few RegEx replace in Notepad++ recorded with a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should really start putting your attempts, even if they fail. It shows what you've been trying and other people can point out what you did wrong so you can get them right in the future.

---

You can use this series of replaces (F means find, R means replace and the second replace is empty):

```
F: (http://[^/]+/)[^"]+","([^"]+")
R: $1$2

F: "<[^"]+"
R:

F: ">[^<]+</
R: ,"

F: ,?\s(?=[^"]+",)
R: -
```

There can be something possible in less find/replaces, I haven't explored all the possibilities. Note that regex does not handle replacing character case, so your actual end product will be:

```
"http://iis.se/The-intro","http://www.google.com","Thank you!"
"http://website.com/The-nice-Second","http://www.altavista.com","Thank you!, even more!!!"
```

Compare against the result you want:

```
"http://iis.se/the-intro","http://www.google.com","Thank you!"
"http://website.com/the-nice-second","http://www.altavista.com","Thank you!, even more!!!"
```

To convert those to lowercase, you could perhaps select the columns and convert them to lowercase if the links are all about the same character length (by press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> then selecting text, you select vertically in notepad++ and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> turns all the characters to lowercase).

Comment: Sorry, I guess that's why I got minus points. But thank you so much for making more than I asked for. Lowercase conversion is not a requirement, so it's all good. **But**, a problem; I ran the find & replace expressions and got a different result than you got. The second got some sort of problem. For some reaspon, the RegEx only works on the the first line.

Comment: After replacing my sample with  `"<[^"]+"` with ` ` (nothing), the output is the following: `"http://iis.se/The intro","http://www.google.com"">here</Thank you!"
"http://website.com/The, nice, Second","http://www.altavista.com"">Donec auctor</a>, ante eu venenatis / (alot of text) / leo.</p>","Thank you!, even more!!!"`

I don't why this would happend. I have changed so both a hrefs are exactly the name, trying some more at the moment.

Comment: Tried removing the comma after `Donec auctor</a>,` on the second line and putting `<a href=""http://www.altavista.com"">Donec auctor</a>` within <p> tags, same problem. Noticed something, might be a problem in the first RegEx also, but I am unsure. 

After #1 Regex: First lines a href looks like this: `molestie et est. <a href=""http://www.google.com"">Donec auctor</a>, ante ` and ending line looks like this `vitae eget leo.</p>","Thank you!, even more!!!"` while the second line a href & endling line looks like this: `<p>Read more here <a href=""http://www.google.com"">here</Thank you!"`

Comment: Look here http://regexr.com?35hfl, only three URLs get marked, should't it be all four?

Comment: @LiuKang Hmm, must have happened when I tried to make the first regex shorter and didn't notice that. See the revised first step: http://regexr.com?35hj1

Comment: This is perfect and seems to solve all by problems for the moment, if some bugs comes up I come back. But now I will gladly I accept your answer, this will save me **alot** of time.